# How to get hold of a reference stored in an enum?

Tags: java, methods, enums

I have a Java enum with an object reference stored in a field. How can I get hold of that reference from outside the enum?

```
public enum TisztításiEljárás  {
    BIO_TISZTÍTÁS(new Időtartam(3, 20))

    private Időtartam javasoltVállalás;

    private TisztításiEljárás(Időtartam i) {
        javasoltVállalás = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: TisztításiEljárás.BIO_TISZTÍTÁS ?

Comment: @casperOne, Why was this closed as not a real question?

Comment: Please explain, your questin properly. Also an example in normal english would be readable by many other people as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as if it was a class.

Make the field public, or add a `get` method in the enum.

```
enum TisztításiEljárás  {
    BIO_TISZTÍTÁS(new Időtartam(3, 20));

    private Időtartam javasoltVállalás;

    private TisztításiEljárás(Időtartam i) {
        javasoltVállalás = i;
    }

    public Időtartam getObj() {    // ordinary get method
        return javasoltVállalás;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
// Get the object
Időtartam theObject = TisztításiEljárás.BIO_TISZTÍTÁS.getObj();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, seems overly simple

Did you try `TisztításiEljárás.BIO_TISZTÍTÁS` ?

If you need to get to javasoltVállalás variable, then you need to add a public getter to it.